# jsoup URL via variable

Tags: java, jsoup

at first: i am not that far into Java.

i am trying to achieve that i create a String variable with a Scanner (System.in) and using this for the `Document doc = Jsoup.connect(variable instead of "www.url.com").get();`

Here is my Code so far, i hope i don't forget nothing important.

First Java-Class where i get the Scanner and the Variable

```
    public static String inputURL() {
        System.out.print("Please insert a valid URL to crawl: ");
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Output: " + input);

        return input;
   }
```

After this i run the Method in the other Java-Class with `static String input = Crawler.inputURL();`

And then want to connect with `Document doc = Jsoup.connect(input).get();`

I get the following Errors:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:              Malformed URL: www.google.de
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.url(HttpConnection.java:101)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:43)
    at org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect(Jsoup.java:73)
```

Hope somebody can help me.

The whole thing is working if i dont use the variable but write the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Jsoup.coonect` method expects the URL to start with `http://` or `https://`. Add this prefix to your URL and you're done.